# How to set different loggers for each ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I have a few ActiveJobs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#queues)

For example:

```
app/jobs/dogs_job.rb
app/jobs/cats_job.rb
app/jobs/rats_job.rb
```

According to documentation I can set the queue name:

```
class DogsJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(dog)
    ...
```

How I can set different loggers for each of these Jobs? I want to have different logger for each of these jobs:

```
app/log/development.log
app/log/production.log
app/log/dogs_job.log
app/log/cats_job.log
app/log/rats_job.log
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveJob itself is pretty limited in terms of configuring the underlying Job framework. I don't think you can set a logger via the ActiveJob API. I would use [the Logger class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) directly to do what you want.